# MSVC2013 and variadic template methods with std::thread compilation error

Tags: c++11, variadic-templates, visual-c++-2013

I have a threads manager class with the folloing methods:

```
template <class _Fn, class... _Args>
void create_thread (_Fn&& fun, _Args&&... args)
{
    std::thread t (std::mem_fn(&MyClass::threads_entry<_Fn, _Args...>),
                    this, fun, args...);
}

template <class _Fn, class... _Args>
void threads_entry (_Fn&& fun, _Args&&... args)
{
  fun (std::forward <_Args>(args)...);
  perform_on_before_thread_exit_tasks();
}
```

In another class I'm trying to use it. This class has the following members:

```
void make_sure_thread_created ()
{
    m_threads.create_thread (
                    &MyClass2::thread_tasks,
                    this);
}

void thread_tasks ()
{
}
```

I get compilation error (MS VC2013):

```
error: C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments
```

It points to this line of code:

```
fun (std::forward <_Args>(args)...);
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or is it the compiler bug? What can be done here?...

Comment: Just tested - VC2015 behaves the same way... Except it does not contain a bug of VC2013 which forced me to use std::mem_fn in the code above.

Comment: Ahaha, this workaroung got it: std::bind (&MyClass2::thread_tasks, std::placeholders::_1), this).

Comment: posted it as an answer. Can someone please correct me, if I'm wrong here?

Comment: Does not work for VC2013...

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's a bug of both VC2013 and VC2015 compilers.

Workaround:

```
m_threads.create_thread (
    std::bind (&MyClass2::thread_tasks, std::placeholders::_1),
    this);
```